# Condensation on air con causing leak, best way to insulate

Tags: plumbing, insulation, air-conditioning

In the roof there is a large metallic air con box, the drip is coming from one of the corners, see photos. An engineer has said we need an external drip tray, and/or additional insulation.

[image: Photo]

WHats the best way to insulate, its dripping from one of the corners shown in pic.

Comment: it does not look like it's supposed to make water, what is this box, where is the water coming from?

Comment: @Jasen I think most air con units have drip trays see pics here https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28822/how-can-i-replace-the-plywood-under-my-air-handler